# MVVM Cross Way of Social Media Login

Tags: authentication, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is there a tutorial or example that demonstrates how Social Media Login handling is done in MVVM Cross? For example logging in a user on Facebook and Android.

I have a rough idea of the approach I should take, ie, the MVVM Cross(MX) approach but if there is a tutorial or example it would be really useful.

My approach is to:

- Use Xamarin.Auth to log the user into Social Media businesses (Facebook and Google Plus)
- Use Xamarin.Auth to create a token to record that the user is logged in  (Save the account status)
- Create a CustomAppStart class that inherits from `IMvxAppStart`. This class will validate user credentials. Is this validation performed at app start or on each page/screen show?
- Inside the above class use `Mvx.Resolve<IAuth>` to validate users. Can/does `Mvx.Resolve<IAuth>` work with Xamarin.Auth?

Is the above approach the MVVM Cross way of doing it? Is there a MVVM Cross class/method that would help me with user login, authentication, etc. that I dont know about?